# Pi-hole seems to be blocking itself

Tags: dns, pihole

I have a brand new install of a Pi-hole on a Raspberry PI on my LAN. I am running into a really funny problem - when I access the Pi-hole instance from my laptop using its domain name (`pihole.lan`) I get an access denied page from Pi-hole.

I am not sure I can understand the message as it say “Not found on any Blacklist.”

Can someone please help me understand what could be the issue?

[image: PiHole error message]

Strangely it works fine when I access the Pi-hole through its IP.  My local DNS is provided by a DD-WRT router.  My first DNS is in the router using DNSMasq (`192.168.0.4`) and my Pi-hole is upstream to the router and the real internet DNS is upstream to the Pi-hole.

Comment: What did you find when you looked for that error on [the www](https://www.google.com/search?q=pihole+lan+not+found+on+any+blacklist)? Did you try any of the solutions? If so, what was the result? Where did you get stuck?
Please edit your question to show your research, this makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the site as suggested in the notification?

Comment: Yes I tried whitelisting didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the [comment posted by @Saaru Lindestøkke](https://superuser.com/questions/1565333/pihole-is-blocking-itself#comment2383931_1565333) and found a [support post](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pihole-local-blocked-because-is-not-found-on-any-blacklist/20655) that outlines this interesting quirk in Pi-hole: If you access the Pi-hole’s default page i.e. `http://pihole.lan` it will return that strange error page.

But if you access it by its IP address you will be prompted to go to the admin page.

Now if you access it via `http://pihole.lan/admin/` then you will land in the admin page correctly.

There were some tricks on that page that outlines how you can tweak lighthttpd to forward the requests but I decided to live with this feature.

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity!